# calling cygwin svn from vim

Tags: vim, svn, cygwin

I am trying to shell to get 'svn log %'.  In order to get this into a different buffer, it seems the best way is to call:

```
:new | set buftype=nowrite | r !svn log #
```

Where `r` puts output from the shell command into the buffer created from `new` and `#` references the filename of the previous buffer.  The problem I have is that my default shell is DOS and my svn is cygwin.  I get

```
svn: E155010: The node '/e/code/branch\project\myproject\main.cpp' was not found.
```

So it seems the shell is passing the DOS path and svn is interpreting it to the base path `/e/code/branch` but then appends the rest of the path using `\` -- which confuses itself.

I've also tried:

```
silent exec "r !bash -c \"svn log `cygpath -u \'" . file . "\'`\""
```

But I get an attempt to authenticate the user.  Which is odd, because when I run the same command from the 'Start' menu or a command shell, I don't have to login.

How do I get svn to behave?
Does anyone have a good plugin for vim for svn?

Answer (score 0):

By making the function SVNLog I have got around the path issues:

```
function! SVNLog()
  cd e:/code/wws_shared/sdk
  let file = system("cygpath -u '" . expand("%:p") . "'")
  new
  silent exec "r !svn log " . file
endfunction
```

I still had the authentication problem where the following output was piped to my temp file:

```
Authentication realm: <http://svn.mydomain.com:80> Subversion Repository
Password for 'jh':
```

I solved this by changing the `silent exec ...` above to `exec "!svn log " . file`, run once, enter password, change back to the original.